# Angular dialog popup disables background access

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

I have been looking for a little while, but it seems like there isn't a way to keep an angular dialog open while still being able to access the background site and not have it disabled. Look at my example image. I don't see a way to pass in some parameter to the MatDialog to be able to do it.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

You can set whether or not you want to have a backdrop using the configuration options when you call dialog.open().

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(UserProfileComponent, {
  ... other config options ...
  hasBackdrop: false
});
```

Comment: Doesn't that only disable the backdrop? and not allow the popup to still stay up while accessing the background app? Soon as you click off the popup, it disappears.

Comment: @coloradoman there could be other differences in our overall setup. 
For me that does the trick, I am able to interact with other items outside the dialog by simply setting hasBackdrop: false.